Highcharts -Can i have a chart with multiple timeline on the same xaxis and yaxis?
I want to create a graph with n timelines with only one y-axis and one y-axis, so that I can compare them with the same date range.
I've tried combining two graphs (line and scatter) and I'm having performance problems. I have a dataset with 6000 events over a short period.
Multiple timelines on one chart in highcharts
I'm open to maybe optimizing this proposal, but I don't know how? is it possible to make a kind of cluster and unfold it at zoom?

In this case, dataGrouping, which is available in Stock, may be helpful.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7amp3rx4/ 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Thank you! I'll test it with my own data, but it looks fine to me! Do you also have a solution if some points are exactly at the same position to display them all?
